# Multiprocessing a python method

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have written a method called 'get_names' which accepts argument as the path of folder containing several python scripts(there could be several folders inside it) and returns the names of all the methods inside those python scripts.

But due the vast number of the python scripts in the folder, it takes a huge amount of time to print the names of all the methods. I am planning to create 3-4 processes which will run on one-third/one-fourth the number of python scripts.

How should I write the method to do this so that my method knows which portion of the script it has to work on?

```
names = name_loader.get_names(name_prefix=params.get('name_prefix'))
```

'name_prefix' could be /users/Aditya/workspace/codes/ where 'codes' contains all the python scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == "__main__":
    calc_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    path = 'list with your paths'
    methode = calc_pool.map(get_names, path)
```

You may have to edit your method, so it splits the list with python files in 4 sublists, in which case each process will process a sublist, which together are your complete list. For example:

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == "__main__":
    calc_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    path = 'list with your paths'
    path = split(path, parts = 4)
    data_pack = ((path[0]), (path[1]), (path[2]), (path[3]))
    methode = calc_pool.map(get_names, data_pack)
```

In this case you have to pack the data, since `.map` only accepts one argument. In that case the method `split` splits your list with paths from something like this:

```
path = ['path_0', 'path_1', 'path_2', 'path_3']
```

to something like that:

```
path = [['path_0'], ['path_1'], ['path_2'], ['path_3']]
```

Keep in mind that processes of multiprocessing do not share data, and that you want to submit as little data as possible, since sending data to each process is quite slow.

Also this obviously increases CPU and RAM usage.

The reason I would choose `multiprocessing` over `threads` is that `multiprocessing` enables you to actually run tasks parallel, while `threads` mostly gives you an advantage in I/O tasks.

Edit: Also keep in mind that `if __name__ == "__main__":` is mandatory on windows systems for `multiprocessing` to work.

Comment: Suppose I have 4 python scripts inside 'codes' folder, how would this snippet know that process1 has to work on file1.py, process2 on file2.py, and so on...

Comment: You have to options.

First: You generate a list with all python files in that path, split the list in each process in 4 parts (the number your cores) and pass an additional flag in the `data_pack` which indicates which index of sublist you want to run.

Second: You split the list before you pass them to the processes and each list in your `data_pack` contains a desired sublist. (This is probably the faster variant)

Comment: How do I provide paths of hundreds of python files?

Comment: You are already able to load those python files, are you?

something like `path = glob.glob('/users/Aditya/workspace/codes/' + '*.py')` should work.

Now `path` contains the path of every .py file of that folder.

Now you can split that list easily with a function like:
`def split_list(alist, wanted_parts = 1):
    length = len(alist)
    return [alist[i * length // wanted_parts: (i + 1) * length // wanted_parts]
            for i in range(wanted_parts)]`

Comment: There is no need to split the`list`, `multiprocessing.map(...` doing this by default. [_**This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks**_](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)